# How to reply to a existing message in Microsoft Teams channel via Rest API(incoming webhook)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am able to post a message to a team channel using incoming webhook(code sample below). What I am trying to achieve next is to reply to the same message whenever I have a new update. It's just a simple message in reply and need not to be conversational bot. I tried searching and found some options like teams bot and microsoft graph api. I wanted to know if there is a straightforward way to do it using incoming webhook or something else before exploring this options.

```
import requests
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

webhookurl = "https://factset.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/******************"
message = {
            "@type": "MessageCard",
            "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
            "themeColor": "FF0000",
            "summary": "Event Happened",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "activityTitle": "Main Title",
                    "activitySubtitle": "Sub title",
                    "markdown": True,
                    "facts": [
                        {
                            "name": "Start Time (UTC)",
                            "value": "2021-06-11 05:48:10"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Last Updated Time (UTC)",
                            "value": "2021-06-11 06:16:15"
                        }
                    ] 
                },
        }

req = Request(webhookurl, data=json.dumps(message).encode("utf-8"),
                headers={"content-type": "application/json"})
try:
    response = urlopen(req)
    response.read()
except HTTPError as e:
    print("Request failed : ", e.code, e.reason)
except URLError as e:
    print("Server connection failed: ", e.reason, e.reason)
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently Webhook doesn`t support to send back message. This can be done by using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post-replies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). You can raise [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be considered as a future request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ravindra-MSFT. As per link you provided, app should have **delegated** permissions(ChannelMessage.Send, Group.ReadWrite.All) to reply to messages. I have given my app those permissions. I am also able to generate tokens but still not able to send messages. It gives error {'error': {'code': 'Forbidden', 'message': "Missing role permissions on the request. API required one of 'ChannelMe.All' or 'ChannelMessage.Read.Group' when using resource specific consent. Roles on the request 'Teamwork.Migrate.Asource specific consent grants valid for the request ''".

Comment: This is the error I get while sending message to channel. 
{'error': {'code': 'Unauthorized', 'message': 'Unauthorized', 'innerError': {'date': '2021-06-28T11:13:43', 'request-id': '56fda9af-3104-4461-8a18-35d3f0a462ec', 'client-request-id': '56fda9af-3104-4461-8a18-35d3f0a462ec'}}}
@Wajeed-MSFT

Comment: @PritamYaduvanshi , did you send those messages to a specific conversation? How did you set which conversation to reply to?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it via microsoft graph using delegated workflow.  [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-beta)