# How to reply to message in teams channel through Incoming Webhooks

Tags: microsoft-teams, webhooks, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I knew this wasn't possible in the earlier versions([Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68021220/how-to-reply-to-a-existing-message-in-microsoft-teams-channel-via-rest-apiincom)), I want to know if this support has been added now.

Is this possible by using some **proactively messaging teams bot**? I do not want to use **Graph API's** since for this I would require Application permissions for **Teamwork.migrate.All**, which is very overkill for this small problem.

I tried using replyToId field in POST request, didn't worked out.
I can't find any alternative solution either.

Comment: Incoming Webhooks do not support replying to messages in channels. They are designed to send messages to channels, but not to reply to existing messages. As mentioned in the thread you referred, you can use this Graph API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post-replies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to send replies to a message in a channel. Please note that using Teamwork.Migrate.All permission is not required for replying to messages in a channel. It is only needed for migration scenarios.

Comment: For regular messaging, you can use the appropriate delegated permissions like ChannelMessage.Send and Group.ReadWrite.All.

Comment: These would be like messaging wrt a particular user, I want to message wrt application. Also I want a demon application, there should not be a login/auth involved in accessing the APIs.

Comment: Currently it is not possible.